# <app-root> is not getting filled

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am a beginner with Angular 2 and have started with a small project consisting of these files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppComponent,
    NgModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'App Title';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<span>Welcome to {{title}}</span>
```

Also, my **index.html** looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am experiencing is that even though everything compiles fine, the `<app-root>` tag stays empty in the resulting page and my template HTML is not getting added. I've tested if it is a problem with template loading by altering the template URL, but it fails to find my template file and compilation fails. This means that this can't be the problem.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've added the `NgModule` decorator and the `AppComponent` class to the `imports` section of your module, which is wrong. Remove the `NgModule` decorator from your `imports` section. Also remove the `AppComponent` from the `imports` of your module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The `imports` attribute should only contain classes which are decorated with `NgModule`.

Comment: it show error after removing import ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this issue when I did an ng build --prod and tried to serve it using a python -m http.server. [This issue looks like what I was getting](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1080) The issue I ran into was that chrome would not load the css or js files because they were incorrect "text/plain" MIME type. I switched over to node and express from python and loaded the files there and everything loaded perfectly. 
Here is the code for running this on express:

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 const port = 4545
 app.use('/', express.static('public')) //public is a folder in the directory where your index.html and other content go
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.redirect("/index.html")
    })
 app.listen(port, () => console.log("Example app listening on port"+port+"!"))
```

save this as index.js and run node index.js and it will run on port 4545 and serve your public directory.

The

> < app-root>< / app-root>

was filled