# Angular SSR configuration on Azure app service

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I work with angular v10 SSR with .net core 3.1.
Downloaded the sample code from here: https://angular.io/guide/universal and deployed to Azure Appservice. On azure Appservice Node.js run and start server/main.js.

here is the result:
[image]

My questions:

- Is the correct way of working like: first time load static files SSR and then switch to CSR?
- On the picture left side: the app running on localhost, and the cURL shows the content before browser would replace it with CSR components. here `<app-root>` tag contains the static files which works correctly. After deploy to Azure Appservice its contains only `<app-root></app-root>` empty tag. Is it works correctly?
- Any Idea why show only `<app-root></app-root>` on appservice?

Comment: Remove the `NgModule` decorator from your `imports` section. Also remove the `AppComponent` from the `imports` of your module. refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754946/15997690) it may help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [cyr_x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7497763/cyr-x) Your answer helped lot.

Remove the  `NgModule`  decorator from your  `imports`  section. Also remove the  `AppComponent`  from the  `imports`  of your module.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The  `imports`  attribute should only contain classes which are decorated with  `NgModule`.